# How is this valid C++? What are these tuples supposed to be?

Tags: c++, syntax, brackets

How is `(1,2,3)` interpreted by the compiler? What C++ feature is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int x = (1,2,3);
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xrfgja4b